# Find negative number within iterrow columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called dataframe and I want to find negative values location. The dataframe looks something like this:

| label | 123 | 456 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2.01 | -9.7 |
| xyz | 5.73 | 5.65 |
| qwe | -6.0 | 3.33 |

I am wondering if there is a way to run: `for index, columns in dataframe.iterrows():` and then inside of the loop, search for negative values row by row. Currently, if I run this with `print(column)` I get a result such as:

```
Name: abc
123   2.01
456   -9.7
Name: xyz
123   5.73
456   5.65
Name: qwe
123   -6.0
456   3.33
```

How do I search these values and get a result of the index, column of a negative number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just access the appropriate index in the series:

```
for index, series in df.iterrows():
  if series[1] < 0:
    print(f'{index} has negative value')
```

Or if you want to check any of the numeric values, then:

```
for index, series in df.iterrows():
  if any(series[1:] < 0):
    print(f'{index} has negative value')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` after converting all columns to numeric:

```
>>> np.where(df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce') < 0)
(array([0, 2]), array([2, 1]))
```